# Why doesn’t Webkit accept my simple websocket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, webkit

I’m relatively new to websockets. I have a simple secure websocket system that does what I need it to do. I’ve been using it in my application for months, and it’s been going great, but it only works in Gecko and Blink, not Webkit. Webkit gives me this error.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://[domain]:8082/' failed: Unacceptable TLS certificate
```

I’m gonna be honest. I didn’t know what a TLS certificate is XD I’ve never heard about TLS in all my years of web development. After looking it up, it appears to be synonymous with SSL, so I assume Webkit doesn’t like my SSL certificate for some reason. Please tell me if that’s not what it means.

So why would that be? Why would Webkit not accept my SSL certificate when the other browser engines do, without a single complaint?

Here is the initial part of my server-side code in Nodejs.

```
var fs=require("fs")
;var https=require("https")
;var ws=require("ws")
;var server=https.createServer
(
    {
        cert:fs.readFileSync([path to the certificate])
        ,key:fs.readFileSync([path to the key])
    }
    ,function(request,response)
    {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","https://[domain]")
        ;if(request.method==="OPTIONS")
        {
            response.writeHead(200)
            ;response.end()
        }
        else
        {
            response.writeHead(405)
            ;response.end()
        }
    }
)
;var websocketServer=new ws.Server({server:server})
;server.listen(8082)
```

On the client side, the connection is made with one simple line.

```
var websocket=new WebSocket("wss://[domain]:8082")
```

This is pretty standard stuff I think. I would expect it to work across all major browsers, but Webkit apparently says no.

Extra question: Is there perhaps an easy way I’m unaware of to automatically update which SSL certificate my code selects to give out? Whenever I get a new one every few months or so, I manually edit the code to point to that most recent one. But if I get a new one in the middle of the night, that means my application will be broken until I wake up. The actual certificate files have drastically different names each time, and the directory they’re in also contains certificates for other domains and subdomains, so I can’t figure out a reliable algorithmic way to select the right one automatically.

Comment: Perhaps whatever your "WebKit" is doesn't recognise the certificate authority that issues your certificate? I take it that's some safari browser on an apple device?

Comment: as for your second question, I've always used a web server that handles the certificate stuff itself, and then can reverse proxy to nodejs such that the nodejs code doesn't need to bother with SSL/TLS

Comment: @JaromandaX I’ve tried on Safari on desktop, Safari on mobile, Gnome Web on Linux, and Gnome Web on Haiku. It appears that no browser that uses Webkit likes the way I make my websocket.

Comment: I take the certificate is valid less than 13 months?

Comment: @JaromandaX That’s correct. They appear to expire every two months. The one I’m currently using has not expired.

Comment: nah, that's cool. I think other browsers also don't like long lived certs either - was a thought